# How to detect near duplicate rows in Azure Machine Learning?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am new to azure machine learning. We are trying to implement **questions similarity algorithm using azure machine** learning. We have large set of questions and answers. Our objective is to identify whether newly added questions are duplicates or not? Just like Stackoverflow suggests existing questions when we ask new questions?Can we use azure machine learning services to solve this? Can someone guide us in the right direction?

Comment: You can use the remove duplicates module to do this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn905805.aspx

Comment: @hamish thanks for your reply. But i want to check semantic similarity also. In our context What is Photosynthesis? and Explain Photosynthesis? shoulf get detected as similar questions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use Azure Machine Learning studio and could use the method Jennifer proposed.

However, I would assume it is much better to run a R script against a database containing all current questions in your experiment and return a similarity metric for each comparison.

Have a look at the following paper for some examples (from simple/basic to more advanced) how you could do this:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4314910_Question_Similarity_Calculation_for_FAQ_Answering

A simple way to start would just be to implement a simple "bags of words" comparison. This will yield a distance matrix that you could use for clustering or use to give back similar questions. The following R code would so such a thing, in essence you build a large string with as first sentence the new question and then follow it with all known questions. This method will, obviously, not really take into consideration the meaning of the questions and would just trigger on equal word usage.

```
library(tm)
library(Matrix)
x <- TermDocumentMatrix( Corpus( VectorSource( strings.with.all.questions ) ) )
y <- sparseMatrix( i=x$i, j=x$j, x=x$v, dimnames = dimnames(x) )  
plot( hclust(dist(t(y))) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can definitely do this with Azure Machine Learning.  It sounds like you have a clustering problem (you are trying to group together similar questions).

There is a "Clustering: Find similar companies" sample that does a similar thing at https://gallery.cortanaanalytics.com/Experiment/60cf8e46935c4fafbf86f669121a24f0.  You can read the description on that page and click the "Open in Studio" button in the right-hand sidebar to actually open the workspace in Azure Machine Learning Studio.  In that sample, they are finding similar companies based on the text from the company's Wikipedia article (for example: Microsoft and Apple are similar companies because the word "computer" appears a lot in both articles).  Your problem is very similar except you would use the text in your questions to find similar questions and cluster them into groups accordingly.

In k-means clustering, "k" is the number of clusters that you want to form, so this number will probably be pretty big for your specific problem.  If you have 500 questions, perhaps start with 250 centroids?  But mess around with this number and see what works.  For performance reasons, you might want to start with a small dataset for testing and then run all of your data through the model after it seems to be grouping well.

Also, the documentation for K-means clustering is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/5049a09b-bd90-4c4e-9b46-7c87e3a36810).